# What will Happen if p-nitrophenol is heated with HCl and then cooled?

Tags: organic-chemistry, teaching-lab

When working in my Lab with p-nitrophenol ,I added some concentrated HCl and heated until  it was fully dissolved. Then I cooled it in ice bath and found a white salt like compound which is not probably p-nitrophenol itself. I am totally puzzled about the reaction involved in that condition , what the product really is . Does anyone have any idea about the reaction occurred in that system ?

Comment: Why do you think a reaction occurred?

Comment: How do you know your white solid is not p-nitrophenol?

Comment: Because the color and state of two solids were different.. p-nitrophenol that was given to me was crystalline and greenish. But the product was powder like crystal and white.  That's why I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

No reaction has occurred, you have recrystallised p-nitrophenol!
The white solid you have recovered is pure p-nitrophenol.
P-nitrophenol is surprisingly soluble is hot water (33g/L at 40C) and crystallises out on cooling. There is no reaction that can take place with cHCl.